# My custom Display template is showing incorrect characters encoding when i edit it inside sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, development, html, display-template

I am working on a SharePoint Farm 2013 on-premises. now using sharepoint designer i edit a display template (.html file) in advance mode under the following path :-

```
all file>>catalog >> master pages>>display templates>>content web part
```

but i have noted that inside the `ManagedPropertyMapping` section i got incorrect character encoding for the `'` where it get displayed as `&#39;` as follow:-

[image]

so now when i save this display template and i publish it , the associated `.js` file was not updated.. so i have to rename all the wrongly encoded characters  `&#39;` back to  `'` for the `.js` file to be updated. so my question is why i got wrong character encoding for the `'`?? now i usually edit the display template inside sharepoint designer in advance mode without any issue..
But today i got this behavioure..could the reason be that i check-in the display template ( the .html file) before editing it in advance mode?? and could other characters got wrongly encoded beside the `'`??

Comment: Which version & build of SP are you using? Are you using any language packages?

Comment: @moe i do not know what is exactly the relation between SP version and the problem i am facing... now i have the following farm build number `15.    0.4797.1000` and i am not using any language packs

Comment: Language packages and particular SP builds have had encoding bugs, which is why asked. I'm not aware of related issues which would've been fixed post 15.0.4797.1000, so likely not related to that.

Comment: @moe Now as i mentioned in my original question, i usually edit the display template using sharepoint designer without any issues.. but this was the first time i check-in the display template and then i edit it in advance mode ,,, so could this be the problem ? second question, now if i fix the encoding by changing the  `&#39;` back to `'` then should i be fine?